# Role of a variable in problem definition in time complexity

Tags: algorithms, graphs, polynomial-time

I am a research scholar in the field of algorithms and complexity theory. The problem that I am currently working is the $[1,j]$-domination problem. Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, with $n = |V|$, the problem asks to compute a minimum dominating set $D$, such that all the vertices outside the solution set $D$ have at most $j$ neighbours in $D$.

Let's say I have an algorithm for some particular graph class $C$ with the running time $2^j \cdot \text{poly}(n)$. Can I say that the problem is polynomial time solvable for graph class $C$?

My main question is, should I always consider $j$ to be a constant, can't it be some function of $n$ that ruins everything?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the vertices outside the solution set  have at most  vertices"?  What does it mean for a vertex to have a vertex?  Are you talking about neighbors?  Is $j$ an input to the algorithm or a fixed number? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I say that the problem is polynomial time solvable for graph class $C$?

Yes, you can say that if you want to.

> Should I always consider j to be a constant, can't it be some function of n that ruins everything?

This is something we usually state explicitly, however, if you call the problem the $[1, 5]$-Dominating Set, then, obviously $5$ is a constant.  If you say $[1,j]$-Dominating Set, you should clarify whether $j$ is considered to be a constant.

Typically, I would write $[1,j]$-Dominating Set is polynomial time solvable when $j$ is a fixed integer.  The problem is solvable in time $2^j n^{O(1)}$ whenever $j$ is considered as part of the input.

If $j$ is considered a *parameter*, then in *parameterized complexity* the problem would be fixed-parameter tractable.

---

In other words: Is $j$ part of the input to your algorithm?  Or is your algorithm "hardcoded" with a fixed $j$ somewhere?

Comment: I have a follow-up question. Let's say I am trying to build a W[1]-hard reduction from dominating set to $[1,j]$-dominating set problem for parameter solution size. In the reduction, the solution size of the reduced instance is a function of the solution size of the dominating set and $j$ as well. According to the parameterised reduction, the solution size of the reduced instance can only be the function of the parameter. Now, the reduction is valid only if $j$ is assumed to be constant, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let the running time of an algorithm be $T(m,n)=a^mp(n)$. If $m$ is a growing function of $n$, then

$$T'(n)=T(m(n),n)=2^{m(n)}f(n)$$ which can very well be exponential. To keep a polynomial behavior, you need

$$m(n)=O(\log(q(n)))=O(\log(n)).$$