# Is variable a constant or a parameter

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-hard

I am working on the $[1,j]$-dominating set problem defined in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304397519307583) paper. In section 4, they study the problem complexity on degenerate graphs and prove that the problem is W[1]-hard for the parameter solution size. The reduction follows from a well-known W[1]-hard problem, multicoloured independent set (MCIS). For a parameterised reduction to work, the parameter in the reduced instance ($k'$) must be a function of the parameter in the original instance ($k$). But, here the parameter $k'$ is given to be at most $2k+j-1$, so is $j$ in the $[1,j]$-domination problem constant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Role of a variable in problem definition in time complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/161394/role-of-a-variable-in-problem-definition-in-time-complexity)

Comment: No, I want to know whether $j$ in the problem defined in the paper is considered to be a constant or not. Since I am working on the same problem, this would help me. @YvesDaoust

Comment: As long as it is mentioned in the problem name, it can be considered as a constant.

Comment: @NarekBojikian That's not correct.  You need to take into account that they are looking for parameterized _reductions_.

Comment: But then they can just exclude it from the name of the problem and consider it as a parameter (usually given in unary encoding, as a part of the input)

Comment: In the paper, I would like to know whether $j$ is assumed to be a constant or not (As it is not clearly mentioned). I am not looking for what things could have been if something else would have happened. Please clarify. @NarekBojikian

Answer (score 0):

It can be considered constant as long as it is mentioned in the problem name.
The intuition behind this is that since $j$ is in the name of the problem, different values of $j$ imply different problems, and hence, we can design a different algorithm for each, i.e. the algorithm itself can depend on $j$.

---

Note that here it is quite important to consider $j$ as constant and consider other parameters, since the problem is clearly para-NP-hard if $j$ is not in the problem name, but the parameter itself, since $[1,1]$-dominating set is the dominating set problem, which is NP-hard.

Comment: The $k$-Clique problem is not solvable in polynomial time.